# Findstr with wild card or greater than "X" Time

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Trying to put a batch file together that will find a string within a text file.  Only obstacle is I want to find values that occur in the evening(PM) and NOT in the Morning(AM).

I am trying to find "XBR Upload successful" however only if exists in the PM:

Exert from the log file:
[3:35:07AM] XBR Upload successful.

I have the following:

```
@echo off
findstr /M "[*PM] XBR Upload successful." C:\Test.log
if errorlevel = 1 GOTO NOMATCH
if errorlevel = 2 GOTO MATCH
```

Wildcards * does not seem to be working for me.  Seems to find [*PM] even though in the log file no PM timing exists yet.

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: why not simply `findstr "PM]"` or `find "PM]"`

Comment: Wow, I feel insanely dumb right now, good thinking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like that :

```
@echo off
Set InputFile=c:\Test.log
Set OutPutFile=c:\LogFile.txt
Type "%InPutFile%" |findstr /M /R /C:"\[.*PM\] XBR Upload successful." > %OutPutFile%  
If "%Errorlevel%" EQU "1" GOTO :NOMATCH
If "%Errorlevel%" EQU "0" GOTO :MATCH

:MATCH
Color 0A
echo MATCH
pause
Start "" %OutPutFile% 
Exit /b

:NOMATCH
Color 0C
echo NO MATCH
pause
Exit /b
```

Comment: This seems to work, HOWEVER, even though the string is not in the txt file seems to goto my match.  Do I have my error levels set incorrectly?

Comment: This is great, however, key string I am looking for is "PM] XBR Upload successful." Seems to find if I change to AM or PM.  Specifically wanting PM.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work as you want because you are misinterpreting what `*` does in regular expressions. Normally it is a quantifier, not a wild card.

The expression `x*` means "match 0 or more `x` characters". But your case is a bit special because the `*` appears within square brackets, so it is interpreted as a character class. `[*]` matches a `*` literal character.

The expression you wanted was `\[.*]`
`.` is the wildcard, and `\` escapes the `[` so that it is a literal instead of the beginning of a character class.

Also, you must use the `/C` option if your search string includes spaces. Since you are doing a regular expression, then you also need the `/R` option to override the `/C` string literal interpretation behavior.

```
findstr /R /C:"\[.*PM] XBR Upload successful." C:\Test.log >nul && goto Match || goto NoMatch
```

But as others have indicated, you could probably get away with a simpler string literal search, without any wildcard.

```
findstr /C:"PM] XBR Upload successful." C:\Test.log >nul && goto Match || goto NoMatch
```

Comment: This works: @echo off
findstr /M /C "PM] XBR Upload successful." E:\Test.log
if %errorlevel%==0 (
GOTO MATCH
) else (
GOTO NOMATCH
)

Comment: HOWEVER, No matter what it says it finds the string whether it exists or not.  Think my errorlevel is bunk??

Comment: @T-Diddy - See my edit. I had neglected to account for your GOTO statements. All fixed now.

Comment: I'm afraid the search string `[.*PM]` won't work as expected as `[]` denote a character class, so you'll need to escape the brackets like `\[.*PM\]`...

Comment: @aschipfl - Ugh. Of course! Silly me. Only the opening bracket needs to be escaped. I've edited my answer - Thanks.